# Tensorflow installation error messages, 'SyntaxError'?

Tags: python, tensorflow, command-line

I'd like to install tensorflow using pip in python 3.7 on windows 10 using the command-line as administrator.

First time installing tensorflow and I get error messages:

> `(SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character) or  (SyntaxError: invalid syntax).`

I have tried the various ways shown below:

```
# OPENING PYTHON AS ADMINISTRATOR 
C:\WINDOWS\system32>C:\Users\plain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe
Python 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:06:47) [MSC v.1914 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

# ATTEMPT 1
C:\> pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    C:\> pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow
                                         ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character

# ATTEMPT 2
C:\> pip install --upgrade tensorflow
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    C:\> pip install --upgrade tensorflow
                                        ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character

# ATTEMPT 3
python -m pip install [tensorflow]
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

# ATTEMPT 4 
C:\WINDOWS\system32>C:\Users\plain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\> pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character

# ATTEMPT 5 
C:\WINDOWS\system32>C:\Users\plain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32> pip install --upgrade tensorflow
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you typing in these commands by hand, or are you copy-pasting them from somewhere?

Comment: Copy-pasted from webpages and stackoverflow answers on how to install tensorflow/packages

Comment: Try typing, perhaps there's some leftover invisible character copied as well that breaks the command

Comment: @GPhilo I tried typing the commands from attempts (1-5) from above, as well as when I attempted setting up a path (see comment to below answer). Still get error messages (SyntaxError: invalid syntax).

Comment: I just realised pip is saved to C:\Users\plain\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\Scripts, does that make a difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

python -m pip install tensorflow
works well on my windows7 system. I am currently using python3.6 64 bit version.
Before you execute "python -m pip install tensorflow" from commandline, set the "PATH" in environment variable to 'python.exe'

Comment: In 'environment variables', I created a new 'user variable for Plain' (my username). I set 'variable name' to 'Path' and 'Variable value' to 'C:\Users\plain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe'. Then I tried 'python -m pip install tensorflow' ('python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.) and 'pip install tensorflow' ('pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.).

Comment: I tried adding the location of pip, ie 'C:\Users\plain\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\Scripts', to 'Path' (separating with a semicolon), but it didn't help either.

Comment: In 'environment variable', set system variables, you need to edit existing path variable, path=C:\Users\plain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe

Comment: In 'environment variable', I set a 'system variable' named PATH=C:\Users\plain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe but it didn't work. I then tried PATH=C:\Users\plain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe;C:\Users\plain\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\Scripts. Now I'm getting a new error message when I try to run python -m pip install tensorflow (Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for tensorflow). But I have 32 bit Python, and I think I need 64 bit for tensorflow.

Comment: Yes, 64 bit python